# How to ignore certain characters in regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex pattern almost working in Javascript. The only problem is that I don't want to pick up '|' or '&' characters. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
/^!?[^:(){},'[]+-]+$|[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to stop the regex picking up these two characters as part of this? Thanks!

Comment: what characters are allowed? share some examples with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to avoid matching these characters in you input:

```
/^(?![^|&]*[|&])!?[^:(){},'[]+-]+$|[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/
```

Comment: Thanks- you answered my question perfectly! Can I ask you one more question please? How would you do this same thing if you wanted to look ahead and match these two characters (as opposed to not matching them like we have done)? Thanks again

Comment: Sure that be done using this regex: `/^(?=[^|&]*[|&])!?[^:(){},'[]+-]+$|[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/`